# Unused characters/character combinations in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, regex

I am trying to pick a value out of a SQL script (in C# using Regex) that has been defined by the person that created the script and can then be replaced when needed by someone else.

I have managed to do this using the greater and less than symbols twice e.g. `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '<<username>>'` and this works well.

The problem I'm having is that when I go to add this script into the database to store it(using an aspx page), it throws the following error:

```
System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$MainBody$tstScriptTextBox="...username = '<<username>>';").
```

My question is: Are there any other symbols that will not be used in a SQL script and not cause any problems with Regex?

Comment: FWIW, I've used curly braces for "snippets" to be replaced in templates: `'{username}'`.

Comment: that's correct it does not like invalid characters.. also if you are doing this in .net 4.0 there is a bug in the version when you validate the page , it's value is set to false.. try different characters that's one work around

Comment: ValidateRequest="false"
<pages enableEventValidation="false">
does not work properly in .NET 4.0 another way around that is to set `Validation = true and do something like`http://dotnetfish.blogspot.com/2007/08/systemwebhttprequestvalidationexception.htmlServer.Html.Encode(your text);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a read of this article [Script Exploits Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/w1sw53ds.aspx) - the Exception is less about specific symbols but as the title suggests, more about potential script exploits.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to have to re-think a few things to get this done properly.